# Capture text between given word and second semicolon

Tags: r, regex

I need to capture  text between a given set of words and the second semicolon.

My data looks like this:

```
x <- "Focal Point (BUGS BUNNY; bugs.bunny@looonytune.car; 888-555-1111)\nCartoon Car (DAFFY DUCK; daffyduck@disney.com; 888-555-1112)\nCartoon Official Rep (GOOFY NONAME; goofy.noname@loonytune.car; 888-555-1113)"
```

I'm using `str_match(x, "Cartoon Car \\(\\s*(.*?)\\s*;")[,2]` to capture `DAFFY DUCK`, but I need to capture `DAFFY DUCK; daffyduck@disney.com`.

I tried:

```
> str_match(x, "Cartoon Car \\(\\s*;(.*?)\\s*;")[,2]
[1] NA
> str_match(x, "Cartoon Car \\(\\s*(;.*?)\\s*;")[,2]
[1] NA
> str_match(x, "Cartoon Car \\(\\s.*(.*?)\\s*;")[,2]
[1] NA
```

and several other placements of what I read to be 'greedy' quantifiers. All to no avail.

Specifically, how can I change this `"Cartoon Car \\(\\s*(.*?)\\s*;"` so as to capture the name 'Daffy Duck' and the email address afterwards? The inclusion of the semicolon in between is fine. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match

```
(?<=Cartoon Car \()[a-z]+(?: +[a-z]*);[^;]+(?=.*;)
```

with the case-insensitive flag (`i`) set, though (not knowing R) I believe the backslashes would need to be doubled.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMP4KR/1)

- `(?<=Cartoon Car \()` is a negative lookbehind that requires the start of the match to be preceded by `'Cartoon Car ('`;
- I have assumed that one or more words (`'DAFFY DUCK'` in the example) must follow `'Cartoon Car ('`; and
- the positive lookahead `(?=.*;)` ensures there is a second semi-colon (assuming that is a requirement).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using `DAFFY DUCK` as one example in the three listed, then just

```r
gsub(".*\\(([^;]+;[^;]*);.*", "\\1", strsplit(x, "\n")[[1]])
# [1] "BUGS BUNNY; bugs.bunny@looonytune.car"    "DAFFY DUCK; daffyduck@disney.com"        
# [3] "GOOFY NONAME; goofy.noname@loonytune.car"
```

Regex:

```
".*\\(([^;]+;[^;]*);.*"
 .*\\(                    everything leading up to the first left-paren
      (...........)       the first/only capture group
       [^;]+              one or more letters other than a semi-colon
       [^;]+;[^;]+ ;      two ';'-delimited fields following by a non-captured ';'
                    .*    anything else
```

Okay, for just one portion of that unsplit string,

```r
sub(".*Cartoon Car \\(([^;]+;[^;]+);.*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "DAFFY DUCK; daffyduck@disney.com"
```

or using perl-regex and lookbehind/lookahead:

```r
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<=Cartoon Car \\()([^;]+;[^;]+)(?=;)", x, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "DAFFY DUCK; daffyduck@disney.com"
```

Side note: I know you said you only want that one substring. I think the above addresses it, but if you think you would ever want to extract multiple portions so that you can pick and choose later, then perhaps

```r
strsplit(x, "\n") |>
  lapply(strcapture, pattern="(.*)\\s*\\((.*)\\)", proto=list(a="", b="")) |>
  do.call(rbind, args=_) |>
  transform(a = trimws(a), b = sub(";[^;]*$", "", b))
#                      a                                        b
# 1          Focal Point    BUGS BUNNY; bugs.bunny@looonytune.car
# 2          Cartoon Car         DAFFY DUCK; daffyduck@disney.com
# 3 Cartoon Official Rep GOOFY NONAME; goofy.noname@loonytune.car
```

where you can then `|> subset(a == "Cartoon Car")` (or `|> filter(..)`) to get the second portion you need. (Just a thought, in case you want/need to be a little more flexible with your substring extraction.)

Comment: Thank you, but I specifically need the text between the words Cartoon Car ( and the second semicolon. I'm extracting the other stuff in other ways. Obviously, this isn't my actual data. I've just created this as some sharable code.

Comment: See my edit @darth_chaos. BTW, `str_match` never returns the substring, just indicates if something matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=Cartoon Car \\()[^;]*;[^;]*")
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/GNYINT) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNDgjB/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=Cartoon Car \()` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `Cartoon Car (`
- `[^;]*;[^;]*` - zero or more chars other than `;` + `;` + zero or more chars other than `;`